# How to get the current user in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, forms-authentication

In a forms model, I used to get the current logged-in user by:

```
Page.CurrentUser
```

How do I get the current user inside a controller class in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 272, accepted):

If you need to get the user from within the controller, use the `User` property of Controller. If you need it from the view, I would populate what you specifically need in the `ViewData`, or you could just call User as I think it's a property of `ViewPage`.

Comment: "or you could just call User as I think it's a property of ViewPage" - So do you mean use Page.user when you're in the view?

Comment: Yes, you can use it like, "Hi, @User.Identity.Name!" in the cshtml.

Comment: So this is how you explain it to a newbie? 
Is it hard to write @User.Identity.Name as an example?
-1

Answer (score 211):

I found that `User` works, that is, `User.Identity.Name` or `User.IsInRole("Administrator")`.

Comment: Just to add to this, if you're working in a class outside of a form you'll either need to `Imports System.Web` and further qualify with with `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`, or directly qualify using the full syntax: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

Comment: Works inside a Controller and if using a ViewModel either inherit from Controller or follow Paul's suggestion.

Answer (score 62):

Try `HttpContext.Current.User`.

> Public Shared Property Current() As
>   System.Web.HttpContext
>       Member of System.Web.HttpContext
>
> Summary:
>   Gets or sets the System.Web.HttpContext object for the current HTTP request.
>
> Return Values:
>   The System.Web.HttpContext for the current
>   HTTP request

Comment: Apparently HttpContext does not have a property named "Current".

Comment: I believe you two are talking about two different things.
System.Web.HttpContext and the static property:
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HttpContext (Which does not have a "Current" property.

Comment: That worked on a non-MVC environment, just what I needed. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 40):

You can get the name of the user in ASP.NET MVC4 like this:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: If you are getting this error `'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found`, I would suggest making an absolute call like this, `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`.

Answer (score 21):

I realize this is really old, but I'm just getting started with ASP.NET MVC, so I thought I'd stick my two cents in:

- `Request.IsAuthenticated` tells you if the user is authenticated.
- `Page.User.Identity` gives you the identity of the logged-in user.

Answer (score 16):

I use:

```
Membership.GetUser().UserName
```

I am not sure this will work in ASP.NET MVC, but it's worth a shot :)

Comment: Where does this Membership class come from? IntelliSense does not recognize it by default.

Comment: The System.Web.Security namespace. I'm not positive this is useful in MVC but I use it with the login controls for Web Forms.

Comment: It's useful in any ASP.NET application that uses the Membership providers.

Comment: This will actually make a database request. HttpContext.Current.User doesn't.

Answer (score 11):

getting logged in username: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

Answer (score 10):

UserName with:

```
User.Identity.Name
```

But if you need to get just the ID, you can use:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

So, you can get directly the User ID:

```
User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Comment: This method return a **System.Guid**

Comment: User.Identity.Name is an instance of System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal which does not have an id property... Is this User different from User.Identity.GetUserId 's User object

Answer (score 9):

In order to reference a user ID created using simple authentication built into ASP.NET MVC 4 in a controller for filtering purposes (which is helpful if you are using database first and Entity Framework 5 to generate code-first bindings and your tables are structured so that a foreign key to the userID is used), you can use

```
WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
```

once you add a using statement

```
using System.Web.Security;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work anymore in MVC 5. Not sure why =/

Comment: Only `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` works in `MVC 5`. However that pulls up the domain name with the username. i.e. domain\username

Answer (score 9):

We can use following code to get the current logged in User in ASP.Net MVC:

```
var user= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserName();
```

Also

```
var userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; //will give 'Domain//UserName'

Environment.UserName - Will Display format : 'Username'
```

Comment: hi @rajbaral This worked for me, what if i want to extract the other information from the current user from the db, example address field.

Comment: @rickyProgrammer you need to write a method to get UserProfile from your AD using that `userName`

Comment: var userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; 
This is just straight up incorrect information.  This call will get you the identity of the Application Pool and not of the web user.

Answer (score 6):

This page could be what you looking for:
[Using Page.User.Identity.Name in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613992/using-page-user-identity-name-in-mvc3)

You just need `User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: This works only inside a Controller; or if your ViewModel inherits from Controller

Answer (score 5):

Use `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`.

This will get the current logged-in Windows user.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explain how it works, and describe when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name returns the current user logged into Windows, the OP is asking for the user currently logged into the web site.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, in ASP.NET MVC 3 you can just use User which returns the user for the current request.

Answer (score 4):

If you are inside your login page, in LoginUser_LoggedIn event for instance, Current.User.Identity.Name will return an empty value, so you have to use yourLoginControlName.UserName property.

```
MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(LoginUser.UserName);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
IPrincipal currentUser = HttpContext.Current.User;
bool writeEnable = currentUser.IsInRole("Administrator") ||
        ...
                   currentUser.IsInRole("Operator");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code:

```
Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
```

Comment: This gets you the username of the AppPool that the application is running as.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(
                    HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);

if (ticket.Expired)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Ticket expired.");
}

IPrincipal user =  (System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal) new RolePrincipal(new FormsIdentity(ticket));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be working in Active Directory on an intranet, here are some tips:

(Windows Server 2012)

Running anything that talks to AD on a web server requires a bunch of changes and patience. Since when running on a web server vs. local IIS/IIS Express it runs in the AppPool's identity so, you have to set it up to impersonate whoever hits the site.

How to get the current logged-in user in an active directory when your ASP.NET MVC application is running on a web server inside the network:

```
// Find currently logged in user
UserPrincipal adUser = null;
using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
{
    var userContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AllowedDomain"], null,
                                                ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer);
    adUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userContext.Name);
}
//Then work with 'adUser' from here...
```

You must wrap any calls having to do with 'active directory context' in the following so it's acting as the hosting environment to get the AD information:

```
using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate()){ ... }
```

You must also have `impersonate` set to true in your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
```

You must have Windows authentication on in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Comment: I do not believe so, as this is explicitly using your Active Directory user credentials. Why would you have 'Forms' if you desire your users to be authenticated via AD?

Comment: In our organization, there are locations where we have a couple of workstations that are shared by several "field" personnel. Because of that, we are required to add the login page to our intranet web applications.

Comment: as a workaround: you could have two copies of this app running, one in 'Forms' mode with it's own identity tables or you can mix both in one app, but it's trickier. A quick google revealed this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250921/mixing-forms-authentication-with-windows-authentication

Comment: <identity impersonate="true" /> might need to change if mixing

Answer (score 2):

In Asp.net Mvc Identity 2,You can get the current user name by:

```
var username = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

If any one still reading this then, to access in cshtml file I used in following way.

```
<li>Hello @User.Identity.Name</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the IIS Manager, under Authentication, disable:
1) Anonymous Authentication
2) Forms Authentication

Then add the following to your controller, to handle testing versus server deployment:

```
string sUserName = null;
string url = Request.Url.ToString();

if (url.Contains("localhost"))
  sUserName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
else
  sUserName = User.Identity.Name;
```