# How do I get the current user in an MVC Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, membership

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get current user in Asp.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263486/how-to-get-current-user-in-asp-net-mvc)

I've tried a bunch of different things, I know I've done it before when I used Webforms, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in MVC.

Membership doesn't work
User gives me an IPrincipal or something User.Identity gives me the same type of variable...

Anyone know? Is there any GetCurrentUser() method or something similar?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263486/how-to-get-current-user-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: wow that's hilarious, I always check the list of recommended questions after I type in the title and the title is almost the exact same... my apologies

Comment: Just tried Page.User.Identity as well as Page.CurrentUser. Both of them give me an error saying System.Web.UI.Page does not contain a definition for "CurrentUser" or "User.Identity" in the case of the first one

Comment: check do you have any class named "Page" within your project

Comment: No I don't. The error says it's referencing System.Web.UI.Page

Comment: I'm trying to access it from within a Control, does that matter?

Answer (score 10):

See Mehrdad's answer here: [System.Web.UI.Page won't let me access CurrentUser or User.Identity from a Controller in ASP.Net-MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045593/system-web-ui-page-wont-let-me-access-currentuser-or-user-identity-from-a-contro/1045607#1045607)

He explains that you can to use

```
User.Identity // in the controller
HttpContext.User.Identity // in the controller
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity // anywhere
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Page.User.Identity
```

Page should be referencing `System.Web.UI.Page`

check do you have any class named "Page" within your project