# Windows users check against a DB table value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a ASP.Net web site which runs on a intranet. The questions I am having is with the login. The users who are admins only can access this web site. This is checked against a Table in SQL. It has each user name and a column called 'isAdmin'. So I want to use windows authentication to log in to the site and show a access denied page if the user is not an Admin. Checking 'isAdmin' column with the windows user name. How can I achieve this. Appreciate if you can find a solution for this.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried with just windows authentication. I am having the question of how to check the users with the DB. Is it a HttpHandler? Or Can I use Forms authentication with a login page to check the windows users and also the DB?

Comment: You need to connect to db and do a select query with condition: user name = @loggedUser and isAdmin = 1. If result will have no rows it means he is not ad admin and he Can't access Your page.

Comment: Yes true. But do I need to work with forms authentication for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the following link for your answer:
[Windows authentication and Forms authentication in same application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074971/windows-authentication-and-forms-authentication-in-same-application)
The reply in the link has a situation similar to yours.