# anonymous authentication on iis7 LOGON_USER is empty

Tags: iis-7, sitecore, windows-authentication, sitecore6

I have a application on iis7 using anonymous authentication. I want to retrieve the LOGON_USER from the server variables. It is currently empty. Microsoft suggests how to populate the values of serer variables [in this post](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306359).

But that is for iis5 & 6. How to do it in IIS7?

Actual problem I am trying to solve is: the application is for intranet and internet users and is a sitecore application running on iis7. If I use windows authentication, I get the domain and username and I can bypass login for intranet users, but for external users, i need to have anonymous authentication also. Having both together will not populate values in the server variables. Have been going through many posts. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250921/mixing-forms-authentication-with-windows-authentication) which says to use Forms and windows authentication.

Not able to solve it properly.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

In order to track a user profile, the user will need an ASP.Net profile created.

There is programming involved to associate a Sitecore DMS/OMS visitor profile with an actual Asp.net profile.  If you want to continue to track Sitecore user profile, you would have to use the `Tracker.Visitor.ExternalUser` and not iis to determine the current visitor on the internet site.