# How to customize Windows-based authentication?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis

I have a site on IIS configured to use Windows Authentication type.
What I need to do is to have ability to skip displaying Windows credentials prompt for users which are connecting outside the domain. In the case of outside access I need to redirect user to custom login page on the same site (based on Windows Authentication).
Can you please tell me if there any ability to do that?

UPDATE : site on IIS configured to use Windows Authentication type - and it shouldn't be changed

Comment: So you want to mix Windows and Forms Authentication? Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250921/mixing-forms-authentication-with-windows-authentication

Comment: Actucally it's a bit different - I'm wondering if I could have a custom action (for instance, redirect to my logon page) for some users

Comment: I think use `form-authentication` at login page check the `ip-address` of the user from where the request is comming and if it is from your domain autometically log in him.

Answer (score 1):

Change authentication mode  your web.config

Something like:

```
   <authentication mode="Forms"> 
          <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" /> 
   </authentication>
```

Comment: I'm not permitted to change authentication mode - it should be Windows

Comment: Even at application level?

Comment: What do you mean? <authentication mode="Forms"> and still keep site configured for windows auth? What the benefit?