# How to make MVC3 application authenticate both Windows and Forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am developing an **MVC3 application** for a customer service team.
I am using **default login and registration controls in my application**.
I have to use **both Form Authentication** and **Windows Authentication**.
For the customers who come online to insert their comments, it will be Form Authentication for them.
For the **customer service staff**, the system has to **use their Windows Authentication to login them** (if they they have logged into the
their windows account the website should recognize their login details and authenticate them.)
How can I make my MVC3 application to authenticate both **Windows Authentication for the staff** and **Forms Authentication for others**?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mixing Forms authentication with Windows authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250921/mixing-forms-authentication-with-windows-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

i think you must create your own authentication on top of FormsAuthentication . 
check this maybe helpful

http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/asp-net-mvc-5-authentication-breakdown-part-deux