# Multi-Authentication mode in same application

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I have a case that I need my application run on windows authentication mode but a specific folder I want to deny access for it and handle it like forms mode authentication

Do you have any suggestions how to handle this case and use something like multi authentication mode within one application !

Answer (score 2):

It's possible - exact mechanism would depends upon where your user store is located at. For example, let's say you have your own users table in the database that you are using for doing Forms authentication. In such case, you can offer windows authentication by mapping your user to the windows user(s) - it can be as simple as maintaining a column in the users table.

Basic idea is to to configure ASP.NET to use forms authentication - the login page uses windows authentication and if user is authenticated then do not display login form. See this link for more info: http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/

On related note, see this SO question: [Mixing Forms authentication with Windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250921/mixing-forms-authentication-with-windows-authentication)