# Using Page.User.Identity.Name in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In MVC2 I have used `Page.User.Identity.Name` using the `<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>`

How can I use the same in MVC3?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can always do something like:

```
@Html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```

but don't.

Normally a view shouldn't try to fetch such information. It is there to display whatever information is passed by the controller. It should be strongly typed to a model class which is passed by a controller action.

So in the controller action rendering this view:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Username = User.Identity.Name
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Now inside the view feel free to use this information:

```
@Model.Username
```

Comment: I have not understood, i`m using    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(user.Name, model.RememberMe); and in another view i`m trying to load the user name using in _LogOnPartial.cshtml using 
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>Welcome <b>@Page.User.Identity.Name</b>!
    [ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text>
}
else {
    @:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]
}

Comment: What`s the use of _LogOnPartial.cshtml in that case? and I just can`t do that for all the views?

Comment: @user281180, you shouldn't use `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` in an ASP.NET MVC application. The correct way of performing a redirect is to `return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn", "SomeController")` after having set the authentication cookie to the response (using [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx)). Then inside the LoggedIn action simply fetch the username and pass it to the view model. So use `@Model.Username` instead of `@Page.User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: Of course if you don't want to use strongly typed views you can always use `@Html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: Can I have an example how I can use the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie please.  Actually, in my mvc2 I have used FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage and since it worked, I have used it for MVC3 as well

Comment: @user281180, `RedirectFromLoginPage` works but it is not correct to use it in MVC. As far as the `SetAuthCookie` is concerned simply: `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Name, model.RememberMe);`.

Comment: One thing i`m confused about is, if I Use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Name, model.RememberMe), next time anyone logging in the system, will be logged as the previous user logged, however, I only want to pass the user status to the page after the login Page.

Comment: `SetAuthCookie` is absolutely identical to `RedirectFromLoginPage` except that it doesn't perform the redirect because as I explained redirects in ASP.NET MVC should be performed by a controller action returning a RedirectToAction result.

Answer (score 11):

MVC 2

```
<%: this.Page.User.Identity.Name %>
```

MVC 3

```
@this.User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I used [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) to solve this issue.

In short, in your view, put this code:

```
@Context.User.Identity.Name
```

Just make sure that the project is set to authenticate with windows.