# How to display Name instead of UserName with User.Identity.Name in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

There are many topics on this issue, did not found one to fit my wish.

In MVC5, in `_LoginPartial`, there is this function `User.Identity.GetUserName()`, which is displaying the UserName of the actual user.

I want to display the Name, from ApplicationUser, which contain the properties:

```
public ApplicationUser()
{
   Name = FirstName + " " + LastName;
}
public FirstName {get;set;}
public LastName {get;set;}
public Name {get;}
```

I have the posibility to use a static function to get the Name, like:

`function.Name(User.Identity.GetUserId())`.

I do not want to query again the database, I want to use this `User.Identity.Name`, but this function is returning the UserName, I need to override somehow.

**How can I get the Name, using `User.Identity.Name`?**

Comment: follow this link it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/4614049/2798643

Comment: Add the UserName claim when logging in, read it from the Identity.

Comment: Can you guys give me more details.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880269/how-to-do-session-management-in-aspnet-identity/32991423#32991423

Answer (score 2):

```
User.FindFirst("name").Value
```

i.e. search through claims to get the display string. 
"name" = display name for the identity fetched.

Comment: Hi @Dkumar, if you put four spaces in front of your code, it'll be formatted as code which helps clarify the different sections of your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Off the top of my head UserManager has a method to get ApplicationUser from UserId. Then with the ApplicationUser object you can get the Name property. Something like:

```
ApplicationUser user = UserManager.GetUserById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
user.Name;
```