# MVC 4 and Ninject: how do I add the client's user ID to my injected classes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using Ninject 3.0 to inject service layer data access classes into my controllers.  I would like to add the client's domain user ID to these classes at runtime, but cannot figure out what approach I should use.  Currently my `NinjectModule` looks something like this:

```
public class NinjectBindModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ISomeRepo>().To<SomeRepo>();
    }
}
```

My question, in two parts really is:

1. Should I use `WithConstructorArgument` to get the user ID into `SomeRepo`, or something else (property?).  Can I even do this in the bind module, or does it have to be done at the kernel or controller level?
2. What method should I use to retrieve the client's domain user ID?  I don't think I can use the [Controller.User property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263853/27457) at the kernel level or in the bind module, can I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class NinjectBindModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ISomeRepo>().To<SomeRepo>();
        Bind<IPrincipal>()
            .ToMethod(ctx => HttpContext.Current.User)
            .InRequestScope();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public class SomeRepo : ISomeRepo
{
    private readonly IPrincipal _principal;
    public SomeRepo(IPrincipal principal)
    {
        _principal = principal;
    }

    ... some methods that will have access to the principal
}
```

Comment: Clear and perfect. Thanks!