# Accessing Models in Partialview

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing an asp mvc application.  I want to access currently logged in user name in partial view. I have checked most answers available on net.I will explain my scenario

My child action is

```
  public ActionResult LoggedInUserActions()
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var user = dbcontext.Users.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == userId);
        return PartialView("_HelloUser", user);
    }
```

in layout iam using

```
@Html.Action("LoggedInUserActions")
```

My hellouser partial view contains

```
 @using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity   
    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated) { 

    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account",new{area=""}, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div class="btn-group show-on-hover" style="z-index:9999">
                    <p style="float:left">Hello! @Model.?
                      </p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="margin-left:8px">
                        Action <span class=" caret">
                        </span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="z-index:9999">
                        @*<li><a href="#">My Orders</a></li>*@
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("My Account", "Index","Home", new { Area="User"},null)</li>

                        @*<li class="divider"></li>*@
                        <li><button type="submit" class=" " style="width: 100%;background-color: darkorange">Log Off</button></li>    
                    </ul>
                </div>    
            }   
            }
```

My question is how can i access the user details i accessed from action method to this partial view? is this a good method to access currently logged in users first name? Can someone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263486/how-to-get-the-current-user-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: i am not looking to get user.identity.name. I want the First name property. Now i added a viewbag in that action method to carry the user name to partial view. is that good?

Comment: Have you declared your model in the PartialView?

Answer (score 0):

Your partial view must be typed after the model you want. Add a declaration such as:

```
@model MyClass
```

and then you will be able to access it through the @Model property.
Another alternative is to use the view bag for sending data. In this case, you need to get hold of the action result and add data to its view bag:

```
var result = PartialView("_HelloUser", user);
result.ViewData["Key"] = Value;  //do change Key and Value
return result;
```

Comment: Well i finally solved it! I used @Html.Action("LoggedInUserActions") with controller and area name.   @Html.Action("LoggedInUserActions", "Home", new { area=""}).