# displaying one user from the list after clicking the log in button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently trying to display one user from the list after the user clicks the log in button, I only want to display the newly registered user and the list of users that are already there should be optional to view

I have this in my controller

```
public ActionResult ViewUsers()
{
    DataAccessLyer dal = new DataAccessLayer();
    List<UserDetailModel> list = dal.GetUserList();
    return View(list);
}
```

Comment: add your cshtml please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the currently logged in user from the `Controller.User` property.

Use this information the filter the list of all users.

```
public ActionResult ViewUsers() {
    DataAccessLyer dal = new DataAccessLayer();
    List<UserDetailModel> allUsers = dal.GetUserList();
    var currentUserName = User.Identity.Name;
    var filteredUsers = allUsers.Where(u => u.LoginName == currentUserName).ToList();
    return View(filteredUsers);
}
```

[How to get the current user in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/263486/1450855)

Comment: thanks mate i appreciate it , i tried your code and it works

Comment: Glad to help :)