# How can we get the Id of an item inside the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So basically as the title said, currently working on a MVC5, how can I get the Id of the list of Items that I have in view of the controller? By a button click, I'm calling an action which doesn't have a view but requires the Id of the item, which is resulting in a NULL.

I read this article but they don't seem to work for me:

[How to get the current user in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263486/how-to-get-the-current-user-in-asp-net-mvc)

```
 public ActionResult GetItem(int Id)
 {
     Item item = new Repository().GetId(Id);
     ..
 }
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: @NemanjaTodorovic, this doesn't really require a demonstration of my code, but I'll edit it.

Comment: @User89 Please show us your `View` code. How are you sending the `Id` to your Controller?

Comment: @RahulSharma I think you didn't understand my question. I have a Page witch consists of a table of items with name and other fields. Now I have a button called Get item which it's supposed to get that item by its ID. Thus, right now when I'm clicking the button it's giving me an error in the parameter stating that the Id is null.

Comment: @User89 I completely do understand  your question. The issue lies in how you are binding your value(Id) and then sending it to the Controller to get your required. Are you using Model-Binding or AJAX to send your value?

Comment: @RahulSharma I'm sending it as Model-Binding (model.id)

Comment: @User89 Try this: `public ActionResult GetItem(int id)`

Comment: @RahulSharma It's exactly how I'm doing it..

Comment: @User89 Notice the `int id` in my case and `int Id` in your case

Comment: @RahulSharma I have just tried it. Stil it doesn't work. I've read on how to get a Users name but regarding getting an Id I cant find anything

Comment: @User89 I guess you are missing out on the point. The link in your question corresponds to an `Identity` which is when a user is successfully authenticated, the context is made with its properties. Now in your case, you have a list of items that have corresponding `id`. When you click on a button, you want that item's `id` to be sent to your Controller method which will return a result (JSON). In order to do that, I need to see what action do you take when you click on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after a discussion on the requirement, the following changes were required to be made on the `View`:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
<a href="@Url.Action("GetItem", "Upload", new { id = Model.id}"">
</a>
<P>@p.Path</P>
</div>
```

And the Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetItem(int id)
```

The `URL` for each item would be generated uniquely based on the `Model.id`