# Is the current user Id accessible in an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC controller if the project uses Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

My site is using Azure AD for authentication I see that `User.Identity.Name` is available and I was wondering if the Guid `uid` is available in a similar fashion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround could able to get the current user id from ASP.NET core MVC application.

We need to use the below :

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

Instead of using `User.Identity.Name` use this `cmd` `User.Identity.GetUserId();`

For more information please refer this [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263486/how-to-get-the-current-user-in-asp-net-mvc)